# Tree file structure from a list in python?

Tags: python

I have a dynamic list which might look like this:

```
['test_data/reads1.fq', 'test_data/reads_2.fq', 'test_data/new_directory/ok.txt', 
 'test_data/new_directory/new_new_dir/test.txt', 'hello/hello1.txt'] and so on
```

I want to construct hierarchy tree structure from this file:

```
test_data
   files
    new_directory
    file
    new_new_dir
       file

hello
```

How can I do this in Python?

Following code will construct list to the root of the file. How can I proceed after that?

```
 [i.split('/') for i in a]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very rough algorithm:

- For each string in the list:

  - Split it into path components
  - For each component:

    - Check if there's a tree node of that name at the current level, else create it
    - If non-leaf, make the node just visited (or created) the current one

Comment: Good enough. How to check the tree node?

Answer (score 4):

You can build a hierarchy quite simply as follows:

```
t = {}
for p in pp:
    tt = t
    for c in p.split('/'):
        tt = tt.setdefault(c, {})
```

The only catch is that leaves are represented as keys with empty dictionaries:

```
{'test_data': {'reads1.fq'    : {},
               'reads_2.fq'   : {},
               'new_directory': {'ok.txt'     : {},
                                 'new_new_dir': {'test.txt': {}}}},
 'hello'    : {'hello1.txt': {}}}
```

Comment: Impressive use of `setdefault` !